# Advice on alternatives to using dozens of check boxes in an interface

Tags: checkboxes

I wanted to get some UI design advice. I am not sure this is the proper forum to ask this question so here goes.

My situation is I have a table that has 51 bit values to hold the values of statutes.

In production, this table would have over 10,000 records for the different LocationID's.

The UI for this in its pure database for would have a page with the dozens of text boxes.

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Any recommendation or links to how others have handled this situation.

Please feel free to post any additional questions if further clarification is needed.

Comment: To offer an UI advice I would like to know something more about the UI than that it has a bunch of checkboxes. What does the checkboxes represent? How is the interface used?

Comment: Who are your target users? Would they have to manually enter all the checkbox values?

Comment: The optimal data model (table with 51 boolean columns and 10000 records, table with 1 boolean column and 510000 records, table with one 51-bit integer column and 10000 records) is yours to decide, based namely on the nature of the most frequent queries you are going to run. Now on the interface in itself : do users need to see or interact with these values ? do they need to do both ? do they most of the time interact with the same records ? how many of them are there on average ?

Comment: Describe the user objective here. We don't care that it's .net or bit values. We need to understand the intents and objective of the users.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to have 2 list boxes, one side are the "Have's" and the other is the "Have Not's" and allow the user to multi-select or move all to one side or the other. This would allow you to hold all the options in 2 boxes, the flexibility to multi-select or select all, and keep all the options in a confined space that wouldn't seem so overwhelming.

Something like this: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial_mixed2b.html but I would also add a ALL to the left or right option if it would be applicable for your needs.

I am sure there are other options out there but this is what comes to mind for myself.

Comment: I like the listboxes idea - if you want to move that suggestion out to a separate answer, you'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: @vincebowdren, yeah no one seemed to find the joke funny so removed it lol.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any kind of logical groupings/sub-groupings of the statutes, you could map the values onto an appropriately aesthetic hierarchical control (tree-view ?) that supports checkbox selection.

This could help with navigation and you could implement select all/de-select all behavior at the various grouping levels to make usage more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the filtering of columns, allowing the User to decide what information is important to them at the moment. This would reduce the overwhelming number of check boxes visible on screen and make the information a little more manageable.